# Calculating distance of points along route using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, proximity

I am struggling with the calculation of the distance between points along a stream (points are located 0-20m away from the stream) in ArcGIS 10. The points are simple xy-data in UTM.

I created a route from the shapefile of the stream and used the tool "locate features along routes" to add the points but how can I now calculate the distances of the points along the route?

Or is there an other tool how to do such a calculation?

Comment: Using Network Analysis or Standard Geoprocessing Tools?

Comment: When you asked "how can I now calculate the distances of the points along the route?" did you mean "how can I now calculate the Euclidean distances between the points?"  Unless that is what you meant I cannot see how the accepted answer applies.  A picture here would have been very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the Near or Point Distance Tool in the [Proximity toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1%20/index.html#//000800000018000000):

> The Proximity toolset contains tools that are used to determine the
>   proximity of features within one or more feature classes or between
>   two feature classes. These tools can identify features that are
>   closest to one another or calculate the distances between or around
>   them.

Comment: @Äirini: please note that there is a 'accept answer' button ( the check box outline to the left of the answer).  http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: I know this is a late response but the Near or Point Distance tool does not measure distance along a route, only euclidean distance.